# stripping out \r from javascript array elements

Tags: javascript, regex

The task consists of pasting from clipboard and the user is expected to past either from Notepad or excel file one single column, so it would look like this

123
233
22.222

etc

I need to replace \r with empty space and I tried many different ways but all of them leave \r in. Initially, the data looks like this 123\r\n233\r\n22.222\r\n

I need to leave the \n in but strip the \r out.

Here is my code so far

```
pasteResultsFromClipboard: function () {

        var clipText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');   
        clipText =  clipText.replace(/(?:\\[r])+/g, "");


        var rows = clipText.split('\n');

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clipText = clipText.replace(/\r/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
clipText.replace(/\r/g, "");
```